# When getting ip of computer it shows 0.0.0.0

Tags: java

So I have this code

```
server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100);
showMessage("Your IP is: "+server.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()+"\n");
```

and I have also tried .getInetAddress().getCanonicalHostName() and some others, and they all display 0.0.0.0 or 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0.
Anyone know why this is happening?
Also, when the client connects with the RIGHT ip, it works, it's just displaying it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`0.0.0.0` means it is bound to all adapters, not just one of them like `localhost` or your network card.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! But when I use Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() it uses my Hamachi address, so how do I point it to a certain adapter?

Comment: If you already know the specific local IP address you want to use, you can explicitly use that in a ServerSocket constructor.

Comment: @user3042719 Some OSes have a weak host model, when means they are free to ignore your hints as which adapter to use. e.g. Linux systems use a weak hosting model. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost%28%29) of these approaches -

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()
```

if you have multiple interfaces you might prefer to use this [one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) -

```
NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
```

Answer (score 0):

What Peter said.  If you want to know about specific local interfaces, look at java.net.NetworkInterface static methods, and from there get a specific InetAddress.  Then from there, if you want to use only a specific local interface, you can pass the InetAddress to the ServerSocket constructor.